# Quantity discount in each product option in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

i have a select option in which 3 option A, B, & c .
in which each option need discount according to quantity.

if option A option price is 200 the after discount on purchasing 10 or more than 10 quantity - price be 190 / unit. and purchasing  25 or more   price is going to 150/unit.

same as in b and c also .

Comment: Can you please explain what you have tried, and what is going wrong?

Comment: yes! i want quantity discount in each option of product.

Comment: Ok, so you need to tell us what you've tried, and what exactly is going wrong.  With the greatest of respect, this site is not here to do your work for you.